# Mutually exclusive random sampling from a list

Tags: python, random, sample, mutual-exclusion

```
input = ['beleriand','mordor','hithlum','eol','morgoth','melian','thingol']
```

I'm having trouble creating X number of lists of size Y without repeating any elements.

What I have been doing is using:

```
x = 3
y = 2

import random

output = random.sample(input, y)
# ['mordor', 'thingol']
```

but if I repeat this then I will have repeats.

I would like the output to be something like

```
[['mordor', 'thingol'], ['melian', 'hithlum'], ['beleriand', 'eol']]
```

since I chose `x = 3` (3 lists) of size `y = 2` (2 elements per list).

```
def random_generator(x,y):
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than randomly taking two things from your list, just randomize your list and iterate through it to create your new array of the dimensions you specify!

```
import random
my_input = ['beleriand','mordor','hithlum','eol','morgoth','melian','thingol']
def random_generator(array,x,y):
    random.shuffle(array)
    result = []
    count = 0
    while count < x:
        section = []
        y1 = y * count
        y2 = y * (count + 1)
        for i in range (y1,y2):
            section.append(array[i])
        result.append(section)
        count += 1
    return result
print random_generator(my_input,3,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply shuffle the original list and then generate `n` groups of `m` elements successively from it. There may be fewer or more than that number of groups possible. Note that`input`is the name of a Python built-in function, so I renamed it`words`.

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint
import random

def random_generator(seq, n, m):
    rand_seq = seq[:]  # make a copy to avoid changing input argument
    random.shuffle(rand_seq)
    lists = []
    limit = n-1
    for i,group in enumerate(itertools.izip(*([iter(rand_seq)]*m))):
        lists.append(group)
        if i == limit: break  # have enough
    return lists

words = ['beleriand', 'mordor', 'hithlum', 'eol', 'morgoth', 'melian', 'thingol']
pprint(random_generator(words, 3, 2))
```

Output:

```
[('mordor', 'hithlum'), ('thingol', 'melian'), ('morgoth', 'beleriand')]
```

It would be more Pythonic to generate the groups iteratively. The above function could easily be turned into generator by making it[`yield`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield)each group, one-by-one, instead of returning them all in a relatively much longer list-of-lists:

```
def random_generator_iterator(seq, n, m):
    rand_seq = seq[:]
    random.shuffle(rand_seq)
    limit = n-1
    for i,group in enumerate(itertools.izip(*([iter(rand_seq)]*m))):
        yield group
        if i == limit: break

pprint([group for group in random_generator_iterator(words, 3, 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) in combination with the `itertools.grouper` recipe.

```
input = ['beleriand','mordor','hithlum','eol','morgoth','melian','thingol']
import itertools
import random
def grouper(iterable,group_size):
    return itertools.izip(*([iter(iterable)]*group_size))

def random_generator(x,y):
    k = x*y
    sample = random.sample(input,k)
    return list(grouper(sample,y))

print random_generator(3,2)
print random_generator(3,2)
print random_generator(3,2)
print random_generator(3,2)
print random_generator(3,2)
print random_generator(3,2)
```

for one run, this results in:

```
[('melian', 'mordor'), ('hithlum', 'eol'), ('thingol', 'morgoth')]
[('hithlum', 'thingol'), ('mordor', 'beleriand'), ('morgoth', 'eol')]
[('morgoth', 'beleriand'), ('melian', 'thingol'), ('hithlum', 'mordor')]
[('beleriand', 'thingol'), ('melian', 'hithlum'), ('eol', 'morgoth')]
[('mordor', 'hithlum'), ('eol', 'beleriand'), ('melian', 'morgoth')]
[('mordor', 'melian'), ('thingol', 'beleriand'), ('morgoth', 'eol')]
```

And the next run:

```
[('mordor', 'thingol'), ('eol', 'hithlum'), ('melian', 'beleriand')]
[('eol', 'beleriand'), ('mordor', 'melian'), ('hithlum', 'thingol')]
[('hithlum', 'mordor'), ('thingol', 'morgoth'), ('melian', 'eol')]
[('morgoth', 'eol'), ('mordor', 'thingol'), ('melian', 'beleriand')]
[('melian', 'morgoth'), ('mordor', 'eol'), ('thingol', 'hithlum')]
[('mordor', 'morgoth'), ('hithlum', 'thingol'), ('eol', 'melian')]
```

Comment: Why not simply shuffling the original sequence(or a copy) and take the items at position `i:i+y` as groups? Is there any disadvantage from the randomness point of view?